# Weird IndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

why is there an IndexOutofBoundsException? It seems as if there is no variable that index may be out of bounds. This program is supposed to convert patterns. Could this have something to do with how I read my file? Thanks.

```
  static int checkNestedParenFront(String line){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++ ){
        if(line.charAt(i)=='(')
            count++;
        if(line.charAt(i)==')'&&count==0)
            return i;
        if(line.charAt(i)==')')
            count--;
    }
    return 0;
}
 String line = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("new.txt")));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("old.txt");
 while(line.contains("F_4")){
            while(line.contains("$F_4$"))  {
                line=line.replace("$F_4$", "$\\AppellFiv");
        }
            int posAppell = line.indexOf("F_4");
            int posSemi = line.indexOf(';', posAppell);
            posSemi = line.indexOf(';', posSemi);
            int posComma = line.indexOf(',', posSemi);
            String check = line.substring(posComma+1);
            int i = checkNestedParenFront(check);
            String lastAppel = line.substring(posComma, i);
            String beforeAppel=line.substring(0, posComma);
            String afterAppel = line.substring(i+1);
             line = line.replaceAll("F_4[^(]*\\(([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),", "\\AppellFiv@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}{$5}");
             line = beforeAppel + "{" + lastAppel + "}" + afterAppel;
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to tell us which line the exception appears on.

Comment: On which line is the exception?

Comment: `int posComma = line.indexOf(',', posSemi); String check = line.substring(posComma+1);` 

What if you enter `abc,d,`

Comment: @DavidWallace it is this line: String lastAppel = line.substring(posComma, i);

Comment: Well, if the value of `posComma` is `== line.length()-1`, you will get that error.

Comment: @user2825125: In that case `int posComma = line.indexOf(',', posSemi);` failed to find another comma, and returned `-1`.
`

Comment: So if there's no comma in `posSemi`, then `posComma` will be `-1`.  Why is it odd to you that this would be out of bounds?

Comment: @JigarJoshi, the input will always be something like this: F_4(d,b;g,y';j,q).

Comment: You should try debugger and see which line causes exception and why

Comment: @Keppil, there will always be a comma after the semicolon. However, they may not be on the same lines. Will it still affect the program if I am reading the whole file in a once?

Comment: @JigarJoshi You're not actually suggesting somebody should use a **debugger** to solve a Stack Overflow question are you?

Comment: @David yes better if OP knows, edited above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `checkNestedParenFront(check)`, you're returning the count in `check` of that last parenthesis, which is not the same as the count in `line`, because `check` starts partway through `line`.

Then when you call `line.substring(posComma, i)`, you have `i` less than `posComma`, and that causes the exception.

I think you mean to have `line.substring(posComma, posComma + i + 1)` - but I'm not quite sure about the `+1`, since it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve.